# Can I do a visa run by going through immigration at the airport and then immediately going back?

Tags: visas, customs-and-immigration, china, airport-security, visa-runs

I have a 10-year China visa that has a 2-month limit on each stay. I usually take the opportunity to do a quick trip somewhere and see some friends around Asia, but sometimes I don't have the time to do this. Today I am making a quick 1-day trip to Korea and back, but I've started to wonder if there is a loophole.

If I book a cheap flight, go through immigration and get my exit stamp, is that enough? Could I "conveniently" miss my flight, the last of the day, and be allowed to pass through immigration, as if I just arrived on a flight, and be granted re-entry? Do I need to physically board the plane to complete the process or do they already consider I have left the country?

Comment: Are we just talking about China here?

Comment: Do you have to fill in the yellow arrival card each time?

Comment: Just talking about China, and yes must fill in arrival card each time.

Comment: What are you going to fill in for Flight No/Ship Name/Train no arrived on? Are you going to sign next to the bit that says "I hereby declare the statement given above is true and accurate"?

Comment: What sort of visa do you have?  If you start exiting and entering the same day on a ME Tourist visa, they might start wondering if you are living there on the wrong visa.

Comment: Berwyn - they would know I missed my plane. I imagine people have unintentionally missed an international flight before, after already passing through immigration. The question is what happens afterwards, and would you be put through arrival immigration again.

Comment: Ok, so you'd put "missed flight" in or something? I thought you meant you were going to claim you came in on a flight. Related: https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/14217/i-stamped-my-passport-before-international-departure-but-i-want-to-cancel-now

Comment: I would check whether your usual visa-run behavior is strictly legal and accepted for your visa type before trying this. Not taking the flight will set up an unusual situation, and there will be a lot more scrutiny than if you were just arriving with a visa in the normal way.

Comment: I have no personal experience with this kind of tricks, certainly not in China, and I have heard about some SE Asian countries where this is tolerated but do realise that doing a visa run is already using a loophole! So if I had to do that, I wouldn't take any additional risk or attract attention to my situation in any way.

Comment: I'm not even sure whether you can reach immigration easily from the departures area of Chinese airports. In any case this Q belongs to expats SE as it is about staying got an extended period.

Comment: Patricia, that's an interesting point. I had never considered a visa-run as something that may not be entirely accepted. I follow the rules on my visas and don't overstay, but I do happen to visit China quite often... It has been twice I just exited and flew back on the same day... I can imagine doing something like the OP, even if it could potentially work, may cause me troubles down the line. China isn't quite as disorganized as it used to be.

Comment: My understanding is that China has been growing more strict about visa shenanigans--attempting to catch people that should be on work visas but aren't.  I wouldn't want to go waiving a flag in front of them!

Comment: @user55655 Look at it another way: If China wanted to grant you (and other people in your situation) the right to stay for 6 months, 1 year, whatever, it could do so at the stroke of a pen and wouldn't issue other, more onerous visas, for proper residence. If the goal is to maintain a modicum of control, it could even allow you to renew your leave to stay from within the country, paying a tax at the local police or something. The two-months limit is there for a reason!

Comment: The fact that there is a restriction on the length of stay, at all, shows it's intended for visits of limited duration. Beyond that, this limit can be very rigid (like X days in Y-day periods rule), up to border guards (as in the US, UK, etc.) or simply not enforced for various reasons. But it's not the same as being allowed to stay for as long as you like.

Answer (score 6):

## Trying to avoid your visa run by just passing immigration is inviting trouble you don't want to have.

**Work your plans out ahead of time and enjoy a day of vacation in somewhere nice!**

From your question I read that you are living permanently in China, i.e. that you have a long-term rent contract there and probably also some type of work (promotion, teaching English, the usual suspects...). This at least used to be standard practice and tolerated by the officials, but [rules/attitudes](http://shanghaiist.com/2016/03/19/call_for_crackdown_on_foreigners.php) [have changed](http://shanghaiist.com/2016/09/12/work_permit_ranking.php) recently. So while the visa runs you are doing used to be a [part](http://www.smartbeijing.com/articles/activities/offbeat-the-mongolia-visa-run) of [popular](http://www.smartshanghai.com/articles/travel/the-cheapest-visa-run-jinmen-island) culture, they are maybe not so advisable anymore.
This just as an intro as to why you might want to avoid additional scrutiny by the officials.

Because additional scrutiny (and plenty of it) is what you will get when you attempt this hack. As you state you have to fill in a yellow arrival card every time you do a visa run, and there you have to put down the vessel number you arrived with. I know that the immigration officials have a system in place that checks flight bookings (for the 72h visa-free transit) against names and they could have no problem checking if you arrived on the vessel you did claim, maybe even in real time while you are at the immigration desk. And there is where you get into trouble, as you have never really left the country, you are effectively overstaying and violating the terms of your visa. That is a bad thing. Next time you have any official business with immigration (and you have frequently as you have to do the visa runs), you will be anxious if they have found out and taken consequences. Avoid all of this trouble by going somewhere nice, or do the quick Jinmen, HK or Mongolia runs mentioned above if need be.

And one more practical issue: from as far as I can recall airside arrivals and departures are separated at least in PVG, so you might have extra scrutiny already when trying to get out of the airport again.